# How to provide file input from command line arguments in R

Tags: r, csv, command-line-arguments

I want my R script to accept data from a .csv file. Is there a way to do this from the command prompt.

Just like if I write Rscript myscript.R 20, it passes a value 20 as input. I want to know if specifying the absolute address of the csv file will allow my script to use the data inside the csv file. If not what do I have to do to achieve what I want?

Comment: You've already hypothesized specifying the file address might work. So you should go on and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?commandArgs`. Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
print(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))
```

Run it:

```
./myscript.R yourcsvfile.csv
[1] "yourcsvfile.csv"
```

Maybe you will be interested in the [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getopt/index.html) package, too.

Comment: I am very new to R. I absolutely have no clue what you are talking about. Could you please explain with help of command line arguments

Comment: @user1523478: Excuse me, but which point you don't understand? `commandArgs` returns the command line arguments.

Comment: Where am I supposed to run this :- ./myscript.R yourcsvfile.csv ?

Comment: @user1523478: In your shell (e.g. bash or whatever). Maybe you need to change the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) if you use a shell on windows. I assumed you know how to run a script because you wrote in your question `Rscript myscript.R 20`.

Comment: @user1523478: What is the error message? (Do you make the file `myscript.R` executable? (bash/linux: `chmod +x myscript.R`))